# Override class of underlying React component

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using an existing React component (i.e. Paginate) which itself makes use of some components (ie. Button). Currently, the Button component sets its class to 'X' which is defined in a css file. I'd like to override the properties of 'X' when I'm using the Paginate component. Is there a way this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used react, but could you possibly stick a parent div around the paginate component and reference the css as .parent .x { attributes }?

Alternatively, you could provide your own over ride CSS file that's loaded after the react styles.

```css
.parent .x {
  /* news styles */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="paginate">
    <div class="x"> x </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as a note, i can't modify the underlying react code of the components (Paginate, Button).

Comment: Have you looked through the DOM to see if there are any parents you can hook onto in your CSS? Alternatively see if you can load your own styles after reacts.